# The type of exp must be an array type but it resolved to double?

Tags: matrix, vector

I'm trying to structure MATRIX class by following these instructions;

1. Constructors: write three constructors
2. Taking a list of vectors as comma separated argument list and converting these vectors from the first to the last to a matrix (Vector is another class to be explained below) and constructing a matrix from these vectors either creating them as columns or rows of the matrix determined by another parameter. (if 0 treat them as raw vectors, if 1 treat these vectors as columns of the matrix)
3. Taking an integer and producing an Identity matrix of dimension determined by that integer.

The following methods are invoked over a matrix object and takes another matrix or any other relevant parameter(s) as needed.

Here is my matrix class;

```
package p1;
public class Matrix{
    public double myArray[][];
    public Matrix(int b,double...vectors) {
        this.myArray=vectors;
        double myArray[][] = new double[vectors.length][];
        int row = vectors.length;

        int column = vectors[0].length;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            myArray[i] = new double[column];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {

                if(b==0)
                {
                    myArray[i][j] = vectors[i][j];  // ERROR HERE
                }
                else
                {
                    myArray[j][i] = vectors[i][j]; // ERROR HERE
                }
            }    
        }
    }

    public Matrix(int d){
        double myArray[][]=new double[d][d];
    }
}
```

I've shown the errors in my code.  I cannot integrate two vectors in one 2D array to make it equal to matrix.

Comment: I think you have your question in the title, but it is best to put it in the question text itself

Comment: My problem is,there are 2 vectors;i have to create matrix with using these two vectors but;i cannot make them one 2d array

Comment: Instead of editing my question,please do something

Comment: i'm trying to help you by making it a better question.  I don't know the answer myself, but you are more likely to get help from others with a better formatted and understandable question.

Comment: yes thanks but no one is coming